# How to make the last letter blink?

Tags: turbo-c++, turbo-c

I'd recently created this program that displays the last letter of a string. Using this code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
        clrscr();
        char text[255];
        int length= strlen(text);
        char lastchar=text[length-1];

        gets(text);
        cout<<lastchar;

        getch();
}
```

If I use `textattribute` or `textcolor+128` and change `cout` to `cprintf(lastchar)` I receive an error which says:

```
cannot convert int to const* char" and "type mismatch in parameter '___format' in call to 'cprintf(const char*,....)'
```

Comment: First of all you must fix the *undefined behavior* you have when printing out an *indeterminate* character. You get the "length" of the arrat `text`, and assign to `lastchar` *before* you initialize the array, when its contents is *indeterminate*.

Comment: As for your error, what did you think would happen when you passed a single `char` to a function expecting a string (i.e. a pointer to a `char`, that is `char *`). And don't just use the address-of operator to get a pointer to `lastchar`, that will *also* lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Lastly, don't use `gets`. Never ever use it. Not only have it been removed since the C++14 standard, it's also *dangerous*. Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: sorry, i'm still completely lost.

Comment: for old MSDOS Is much better to use direct VRAM access in text mode `0xB800:0000h` but that can lead to problems on newer **OS** without proper priviledges. Another option is to use gotoxy and periodicaly rewrite the last place with character and space in some loop with dellay.  (Those work with printf I think havent used console for more then  decade) As mentioned you should add null termination of the string so before using printf/cout add `text[length]=0` and hope the `255` is big enough buffer size

Comment: `int cprintf(const char *format[, argument, ...]);` is used like this: `cprintf("%c",lastchar)` or  `cprintf("%s",text)`

Comment: @Spektre thank you, you are a lifesaver

Comment: @JaneDoe reedited answer see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<conio.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    for (int i=32;i<256;i++)
        {
        textcolor(i);
        cprintf("%c",i);
        }

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the colors are set with:

```
textattr(full_attribute);
textcolor(font_color);
textbackground(background_color);
```

The blinking does not work on my console (Win7) so if you got the same problem you need to animate your self try this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    char *txt="text\0";

    _setcursortype(0);  // hide cursor
    for (;;)
        {
        gotoxy(1,1);    // print position
        textattr(7);    // white on black
        cprintf("%s",txt);
        sleep(1);       // wait 1 sec
        gotoxy(1,1);    // print position
        textattr(0);    // black on black
        cprintf("%s",txt);
        sleep(1);
        if (kbhit()) { getch(); break; } // stop on any key hit
        }
    // restore console properties
    textattr(7);
    _setcursortype(1);
    return 0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use textcolor(); 
128 code is blink code in turboc++

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
      clrscr();
      textcolor(128+6); // or textcolor(134) [128:blinking and 6:brown color]
      cprintf("My name is Prashant");
      getch();      }
```

**for more help right click on turboC++ window and type textcolor();**

[image]