# making numeric input value blink with different color for sudoku game

Tags: c++, console-application

I am currently working on a sudoku game and I need help in adding a functionality that will make a value I input after selecting a row and column to flash red if wrong and green if correct

how do you make an input value flash green color when the right number is inputed by the user.
this is what my code look like for now.

```
if (randomize == 1)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
        {
        printGrid1();
        cout << "Select row number: ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Select column number: ";
        cin >> col;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Input Answer: ";
        cin >> maybe;
        cout << endl;
            //Funtion to restart game
            if ( col == 10|| row == 10 || answer ==10)
            {
                printTitle();
                selectDifficulty();
            }
            //Check for out of bound cells
        if (row > 9 ||col>9 ||row <1|| col<1)
            {
                cout << "This row or column is not in the Sudoku Board"<< endl;
            }

        answer = easyGuessNumGrid1Answer[row-1][col-1];
            if (maybe != answer){

                score = score - 5;
                cout << "Your score is :" << score <<endl;
            }

        if (maybe == answer)

            {
                cout << "Good job! " << maybe << " was the right number. " << endl;
                easyGuessNumGrid1[row-1][col-1] = answer;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "incorrect, please try again..." << endl;
                i--;
            }
        }}
```

Comment: What IDE you are using? see [How to make the last letter blink?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36592399/2521214) If you do not have those function used there at disposal try to look for their equivalents in your IDE.

Comment: Fancy console handling is very OS specific. Can you tell which OS you're using ?

Comment: X El Capitan, and I am working with Xcode